# How to make a fragment visible programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity.kt along with its related MainActivity.xml.

I also have a Fragment that is a part of the MainActivity and it is consists of a MyFragment.kt and MyFragment.xml.
Within the MyFragment.xml I've specified that the MyFragment is Invisible, which means that wne the app starts and the MainActivity gets laid out, that MyFragment is not visible to the user.

I also have a MakeMyFragmentVisibleButton that's part of the MainActivity which, when clicked, I want to cause the MyFragment to become visible.

I am ASSUMING that while the MyFragment is Invisible all buttons or other controls that might be IN that MyFragmment are effectively UN-available to the user. He can't see them, can't interact with them.

BUT when the MakeMyFragmentVisibleButton is clicked by the user I want the MyFragment to become visible and thereby make any controls that might be within the MyFragment become visible and the user can interact with them.

That is how I WANT it to work.

BUT I can't figure out how to cause the MyFragment to become visible. I have succeeded in setting an onClickListener for the Button and it does indeed get called when the user clicks the button. But I haven't figured out WHAT CODE actually must run in order to make the MyFragment VISIBLE.

I looked at dozens of YouTube videos and online documents but they all seem to be written in JAVA. My app is in Kotlin which, unfortunately I have zero experience with (I have 45 years experience as a software engineer but I'm baffled by Kotlin).

So, if someone could PLEASE enlighten me as to what I need to do in Kotlin code to cause a Fragment to become visible (and correspondingly IN-visible) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not scream. Please edit your title and content else this will be flagged for moderator intervention. This is not how we treat our peers. Please use *italics* for emphasis (wrap text in `*`). Also please don't add unrelated text like "MAN, DO I NEED HELP!!".

Comment: Also, please add the relevant sections of code you're having problems with.

Comment: Please do not use all caps. There are plenty of formatting options on this platform, incl. italics and bold (though they should be used sparingly). You can ***[edit (change)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34595896)*** your question. (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hide(Fragment)
show(Fragment)

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments

```
val fragment1=Fragment1()
val fragment2=Fragment1()

    innerMainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(frameLayout.id, fragment1, "fragment1")
            .add(frameLayout.id, fragment2, "fragment2")
            .hide(fragment2)
            .show(Fragment1)
            .commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for that bit of code, but doesn't it need something like a GetFragmentById or something like that? And what ID would I provide to it, the id of its xml code? Or what?

Comment: Does doing the .show operation on a fragment within an Activity ALSO cause that fragment to be active, with all of its controls, such as buttons, etc. becoming active and the user able to interact with it? Or does some form of startActivity() need to also be called on the now-showing Fragment?

Comment: I have updated it in detail, you still don't understand, you can read the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager?hl=en